# Phone simulator size in xcode 8.0

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, xcode8

I am naive to iOS development and using xcode in vmware. My main problem is that whenever I run my application even with different simulator versions, all time the simulator is of the same size and it is huge. 
Is there any way to adjust the simulator size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the simulator

```
form menu -> Window->Scale->33%
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply but can't see scale option in windows option

Comment: Thank you so much!  Working well;)